# How to have 2 different metadata to 2 images in same page?

Tags: php, html, metadata, meta-tags

I have a page where I show several different images through a link with GET to show only one image at a time from a database.
I wanted the page to read different metadata for each image that was displayed.
Example:

If I open the page index.php or if I open index.php?p=[somenumber]

```
<?php
///////////////////////////////////////////////
if(isset($_GET['p'])){
    include 'inc_host.php';
    $p1=$_GET['p'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM upload WHERE p = $p1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $meta_t = $row["title"];
            $meta_c = $row["content"];
        }
    }

    $meta_img = "img.jpg";
    ?>
  <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $meta_t; ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $meta_c; ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/index.php?p=<?php echo $p1; ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.example.com/<?php echo $meta_img; ?>" />
<?php }

else
{
?> 
<meta property="og:title" content="My title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="My content." />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.example.com/img_index.jpg" />
<?php
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
?>
```

The code works in HTML but if I use the link www.example.com/index.php?p=[somenumber] to post on facebook, I get this error:
[facebook error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXJc4.jpg)

Facebook dont read my metadata!

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. The sample you posted doesn't have any "meta data", it's just a link. Show us what you've tried that isn't working as you expect it to.

Comment: Great, please show us what you have tried that isn't working.

Comment: Sorry but that's not how SO works. You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We'll more than happy to help but you have to try first and show us that effort so we can help you.

Comment: @Dave, see my example. Thank you

Comment: Your are outputting your meta tags outside of the `while` loop so only the last entry from the database will ever be output. I don't know what that error from FB means but it likely contains more details about what the problem is.